# How to resolve "Invalid string or buffer length" after calling resultset.getString() connection from java to access mdb

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I am having some trouble with my java app querying an Access DB (.mdb). I am getting this error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
```

but only when attempting to call `resultset.getString("xxx")` on certain rows. About half of the rows that I am querying process just fine but the other half give me this error. It seems like a problem with the data in the row itself but I can't quite figure out what would cause this.

Comment: It sounds like the error happens consistently on some rows and not others. If so, can you create a minimal test case by making a copy of the table in a separate database, deleting all rows except for one or two of the troublesome ones, and then make that database file (.mdb or .accdb) available for download via a service like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com/) so we can investigate the issue?

Comment: I found out that this has something to do with the specific JDK I am using. Running on a PC with 1.6.0_xx had issues but running on a PC with 1.7.0_xx works with no problems at all.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please consider posting your findings as an answer so that it might help others in a similar situation. (On Stack Overflow it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.)

Comment: I would have posted it as an answer if I found a more specific reason why this happens with one JDK versus the other. It actually would be nice to know the actual reason so I can fix it on my dev box without changing my environment if possible. Thanks for the info though!