# Why does my code run fine in Eclipse but throws an error from cmd?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

This question was [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371457/how-to-resolve-invalid-string-or-buffer-length-after-calling-resultset-getstri) asked, and the answer was to use JDK 1.7 instead of JDK 1.6

My problem is **I am using JDK 1.7**, but still get `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length` for line `resultSet.getString("field_name");`

When I compile using Eclipse everything works perfect, but when I compile from `cmd`, it throws this error.

Here is what I do

```batch
set path=%path%;C\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin
javac -cp ".;..jar;" MainClass.java
java -cp ".;..jar;" MainClass
```

Comment: Try to use this in that command window: `where java`

Comment: `where java` results in `C:|Windows\System32\java.exe`  next line `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe`

Comment: Error when running from cmd is `Invalid string or buffer length` for the line `resultSet.getString("field_name")`

Comment: If you run the following from the command line, does it also give you the expected Java version? `java -version`

Comment: Yes. It gives the expected java version jdk1.7._51